# Force download ALL my photos on PC (iCloud for Windows)

Tags: icloud, windows

So I got the iCloud for Windows app in order to download **all** my photos from iCloud to my hard drive. This app is basically required for this because you can only download 1000 photos at a time from iCloud Web. So I installed the app, checked off every box for photos there, and left it to itself for a few hours. Now in my iCloud Photos directory, there isn't anything yet, not a single picture and it's been 2.5 hours already. Is it not working and maybe I have to click some hidden "Download" button for it to start?

Also found an answer on ["How to download entire iCloud Photo Libary to Windows PC"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404494/475307) and it says to click **Always keep on this device** but I do not have this option

[image: Screenshot of the contextual menu for the iCloud Photos]

Comment: My initial guess is that the contextual menu in the linked answer is for the ** actual photos themselves** and not a right-click on the iCloud Photos folder. Have you tried right-clicking on a photo?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post there isn't a single picture inside this folder